# Getting error while trying to run Get-AzStorageBlob

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I want to see the storage blobs of my storage containers in a particular storage account
so I ran the below commands :

```
    $storageAccountName = "teststor"
    $resourceGroup = "RgDev"
    $StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName).Value[0]
    $context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountkey
    Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context

$ContainerName = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context
```

Now when i run the final command :

```
 Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $context
```

i get the below error :

```
   PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>  Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $ctx
Get-AzStorageBlob : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 
'Container'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:31
+  Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $ctx
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzStorageBlob], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzur 
   eStorageBlobCommand
```

Any idea how to fix this

I get this error now

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $AzContainer = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $AzContainer


   Blob End Point: https://testhalifax.blob.core.windows.net/

Name                 PublicAccess         LastModified                                                          
----                 ------------         ------------                                                          
koltest1             Off                  9/20/2020 2:22:04 AM +00:00                                           
teststorhal          Off                  9/1/2020 8:25:44 PM +00:00                                            



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $BlobContainer = $AzContainer.CloudBlobContainer

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $BlobContainer


   Blob End Point: https://testhalifax.blob.core.windows.net/

Name                 Uri                                                          LastModified                  
----                 ---                                                          ------------                  
koltest1             https://testhalifax.blob.core.windows.net/koltest1           2020-09-20 02:22:04Z          
teststorhal          https://testhalifax.blob.core.windows.net/teststorhal        2020-09-01 20:25:44Z          



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ContainerName = $BlobContainer.Name

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ContainerName
koltest1
teststorhal

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>  Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $context
Get-AzStorageBlob : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 
'Container'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:31
+  Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $context
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzStorageBlob], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzur 
   eStorageBlobCommand
```

Comment: The error reported is different than the command you have pasted. the error shows `$ContainerName.Name` whereas your code snippet shows `$ContainerName`. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragecontainer?view=azps-5.5.0 `Get-AzStorageContainer` should just output a string.

Comment: Sorry the earlier screenshot was wrong, i put the correct error now

Comment: may be this is returning multiple containers `$ContainerName = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context`

Comment: Yes, @TheGameiswar you are right, i have more than one containers when i run $ContainerName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragecontainer?view=azps-5.5.0 the command `Get-AzStorageContainer` returns an object of type `AzureStorageContainer`. You will want to dot reference the `CloudBlobContainer` property of that object and then dot reference the `Name` property of that object. So in order to get the `$ContainerName` you will want to do something like

```
$AzContainer = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context
$BlobContainer = $AzContainer.CloudBlobContainer
$ContainerName = $BlobContainer.Name
```

Comment: I get the error attached in my main thread. Actually, i have more than one container as you can see when i type in $AzContainer

Comment: At that point, we would need to know which of those container names you wanted. If you just want whichever comes first, you could do `$ContainerName[0]` which would get you the first name in the list (as $ContainerName would appear to be an array of names). If you wanted a specific container, you would need to adjust your command to only retrieve the specific container. Or if you want to do something with each container, a loop would work.

Comment: If my Answer helped you out and/or was the correct answer, it helps out if you mark my answered as "Accepted". Thanks!